# Can't understand filter and findIndex in the following code? in react-redux reducer function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

In this code

```
 **reducers: {
    addDiary(state, { payload }: PayloadAction<Diary[]>) {
      const diariesToSave = payload.filter((diary) => {
        return state.findIndex((item) => item.id === diary.id) === -1;
      });
      state.push(...diariesToSave);
    },**
```

state.findIndex((item)=>item.id === diary.id) is returning index number
but when we make it equal -1 to my understanding in filter it will always be false cuz index start with 0. so how are we pushing the diary to the state? I'm new and learning redux from following article : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/08/redux-real-world-application/

The code I'm referring to is almost in the middle of the article

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how questions should be written.

Comment: and even if no index found it will return -1 but when 1 diary is added  what happen then? i might be completely misunderstanding things could someone explain whats happening here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findIndex` method will either return the index of the item which meets the condition `item.id === diary.id` or return -1 in case the condition never gets true.

And the `filter` method in the code will only return those items which are meeting the below condition:
`state.findIndex((item) => item.id === diary.id) === -1;`

So, in case `findIndex` returns 0 the `filter` method will not add that item to `diariesToSave` array since 0 is not equal to -1. Only those items will be added to `diariesToSave` array where the `findIndex` method will be returning -1.

Hope that clears out your confusion.

Comment: thanks bro for reply one confusion: How could index be -1 as index start with 0 ?

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote and accept my answer. :)